# Python lstrip Sometimes Removes Extra Character

Tags: python-2.7

I have Python 2.7 code that operates on a list of files.  In part of the code I strip away the directory information.  Today I was surprised to find that code didn't work correctly, when the file names begin with "s".  This sample code demonstrates the problem:

```
import os

TEST_RESULTS_DIR = ".." + os.sep + "Test Results"

filename = TEST_RESULTS_DIR + os.sep + "p_file.txt"
stripped_filename = filename.lstrip(TEST_RESULTS_DIR + os.sep)
print ("%s : %s") % (filename, stripped_filename)

filename = TEST_RESULTS_DIR + os.sep + "s_file.txt"
stripped_filename = filename.lstrip(TEST_RESULTS_DIR + os.sep)
print ("%s : %s") % (filename, stripped_filename)
```

When I run this code, I get this:

> ..\Test Results\p_file.txt : p_file.txt
>
> ..\Test Results\s_file.txt : _file.txt

Does anyone understand why?

Answer (score 1):

Lstrip doesn't replace a string at the beginning of another string, it strips all characters that match the characters in the string argument from the string it is called on.

For example:

```
"aaabbbc".lstrip("ba") = "c"
```

Your directory has an s in it, so it get's striped, you would see the same result if the file started with a u or an e.

Comment: Thanks, you're right that I was thinking it'd only strip the whole string.

Comment: you need to use re module, re.sub(re.escape(TEST_RESULTS_DIR + os.sep), '', filename)